# Tensorflow GradientTape returns NaNs when using MultivariateNormalTriL distribution

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm using network outputs to instantiate MultivariateNormalTriL distribution from tensorflow_probability and GradientTape to record gradients after calculating loss.

After random number of training steps GradientTape returns NaN values for some layers of the network. All the values in the outputs of the network and the distribution look ok. They are some random numbers. Not to small, not to big. All the calculated loss values are also ok. There are no NaNs anywhere else except in the gradients from the GradienTape.

Also, everything works fine when using Normal distribution.

As I understood, GradientTape should only return NaNs when the function is not differentiable. So it turns out that MultivariateNormalTriL is not differentiable for some specific values.

Am I missing something? Do you have any idea how to solve this or at least where to look?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was with the standard deviation matrix. I used [tfp.bijectors.FillScaleTriL](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/bijectors/FillScaleTriL) to transform the matrix and it seems to be working for now.